# заполнение бланков excel

Tags: excel

Бывают такие бланки, как на приложенном изображении, где каждая буква в отдельной ячейке. Чтобы заполнить их приходится нажал букву -> Tab -> Нажал букву -> Tab и тд.
Как-то можно сделать так, чтобы набрал в строку, а excel сам раскидал по ячейкам?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А еще бывает, что в таких бланках буква вписываетсчя в объединенную ячейку. А еще иногда есть требование, чтобы игнорировались пробелы, если попадают в первую ячейку строки.И т.к. задача не описана полностью, то и помогать никак не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Набрать строку так, чтобы после каждого символа был пробел (или запятая, точка, двоеточие). А затем выбрать ячейку с данной строкой -> Данные -> Текст по столбцам -> В качестве разделителя выбрать "пробел" (или запятая, точка ...) -> Готово.
И можно это действие перенести в макрос, чтобы автоматизировать.